# Highlight members and properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to highlight C# class members and properties in Visual Studio 2010 
(declaration and accessing) ?

Comment: Do you want them always highlighted? You can highlight each individual item (class member, method, property, etc.) by simply clicking on it. Visual Studio will highlight all uses of the item in the class. I believe that Eclipse works in the same fashion.

Comment: yes thanks but I would like highlight them permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately VS can't highlight member variables by itself. There are several third party options, though. One of them (not for free but overall great) is [Jetbrains Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html).
There are also free-to-use [nightly builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.1.2+Bugfix+Builds) which you can try out before purchasing.

Comment: Thanks Simon but it's quite a big stuff

Comment: That is certainly true but once you got, you're gonna love it ;) Maybe you should browse the VS Extensions Manager for a more suitable solution.

Comment: Here's how to actually do it with R#: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look to [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2/?SRC=Home) Visual Stiudio 2010 extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find a general highlighting menu :

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

But I am not sure you can highlight class members and "regular" code, as highlighting is mainly for keywords.

If you REALLY Need this feature and have time to spend, try the *Managed Extensibility Framework* in VS2010 : [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885121.aspx)

Comment: No you can't highlight members by this menu.